# Quant Interview Question - Die Rolls

Tags: probability, dice

You have a fair 6 sided die. You roll the die and keep track of the outcomes as they appear. You roll until you see two 5s (not necessarily consecutive) or both 4 and 6. Find the probability you stop rolling due to seeing two 5s (this is on the site QuantGuide).

My approach was to set up some recursive equations and then solve for them. You start of in position A.

Here are the description of the positions

A - Neutral.

B - Rolled a 5.

C - Rolled a 4 (No 5 Rolled)

D = Rolled a 4 having rolled a 5 previously.

$A = \frac46 \cdot A + \frac16 \cdot B + \frac16 \cdot C$

$B = \frac16 \cdot D + \frac46 \cdot B + \frac16 $

$C = \frac16 \cdot C + \frac16 \cdot B + \frac36 \cdot A$

$D = \frac16 \cdot D + \frac36 \cdot B + \frac16$

I solved this and got $A = \frac{36}{49}$ but the site is saying that is not correct. Anyone have any approaches to this problem or a better way to solve it.

Comment: Do you need to see the $4$ *before* the $6$? That’s not the way I read the question but seems to be what you are assuming in your solution.

Comment: And apparently, if I'm reading your equations right, the 4 and 6 also need to be consecutive? You really need to clearly specify the problem, both for yourself and for us. If what you wrote in the first paragraph is copied exactly from the problem statement, your interpretation is very different from mine. (I get 7/18.)

Comment: A link to the original question might help.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question as the "not consecutive" was placed only after seeing two 5s but not after the statement about seeing 4 and 6

Comment: @minmaxFlow: But where is die face $6$ in your equations ?

Comment: Attach the link or at least mention the problem name

Answer (score 1):

$\mathtt{ One\; interpretation\;
 of\; the\; question}$

$4$ and $6$ *may occur in any order consecutively* to "win"

With this interpretation. and using $S$ (for start and neutral state}, and $A,B,C$ for states $4,6,5$ respectively and *probabilities* moving between  states with identical *but small case letters*, we have

$s = \frac36 s + \frac16 a + \frac16 b + \frac16 c \tag1$

$a = \frac36 s + \frac16 a + \frac16*0 + \frac16 c \tag2$

$b = \frac36 s + \frac16* 0 + \frac16 b + \frac16 c \tag3$

$c = \frac36 s + \frac16 a + \frac16 b + \frac16 * 1 \tag4$

[which yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s+%3D+%283%2F6%29s+%2B+%281%2F6+%29a+%2B+%281%2F6%29b+%2B+%281%2F6+%29c%2C+a+%3D+%283%2F6%29s+%2B+%281%2F6+%29a+%2B+%281%2F6%29*0+%2B+%281%2F6+%29c%2C+++b+%3D+%283%2F6%29s+%2B+%281%2F6%29*+0%2B+%281%2F6+%29b+%2B+%281%2F6%29c+%2C+c+%3D+%283%2F6%29s+%2B+%281%2F6%29+a+%2B+%281%2F6%29b+%2B+%281%2F6%29*1) P(see two $5's$ before a $ 4$ and a $6$)  $\Large = s = \frac1{3}$

Comment: I think OP meant to type B = 1/6 * D + 4/6 * B + 1/6. Making that change in the WA input I get 36/49.

Comment: Yes that was a typo - fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I think the question is badly worded, but I have a hunch (due to the apparent simplicity of the result here) that this interpretation was the desired one. (The interpretation in the other answer seems more natural to me, but the wording is so ambiguous that I have doubts.)

Comment: @DavidK: Yea, ambiguous questions are a real  bane. And to be asked such a question in an *interview* !

Comment: Supposedly an ambiguous question is a way to see how the interviewee communicates. But the question then is whether most interviewers know how to use the question that way. I don't think I do.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation that makes the most sense to me is that consecutivity of rolls is never required. So the process stops once you have seen a ⚃ and ⚅ previously or a 2 ⚄'s previously. For shortness I'll use game language and say you win or loose depending on if the stop happens on a 5 or not.

At any given time, since the die is fair, the 6 potential orders in which you will see the first next 4,5 or 6 are all equally likely.

It turns out that looking at when the first 5 occurs is enough, so there are 3 cases, each with probability $\frac13$.

1. You see the 5 first.

Again, from now on the 6 orders of first 4,5 or 6 are equally likely. You win if the first 5 from now on (which is the second 5 overall) is on position 1 or 2, you loose if it is on position 3. That means you win in this case with probability $\frac23$

2. You see the 5 second.

Now it depends which number comes next, 5 or the other number from $\{4,6\}$ you haven't seen yet. Both outcomes are equally likely, so you win with probability $\frac12$ in this case.

3. You see the 5 last.

You already lost, the game stopped once the second of $\{4,6\}$ was rolled. So the probability to win is $0$ in the case.

That means the overall probability to stop on a 5 is

$$\frac13\left(\frac23 + \frac12 + 0\right)= \frac7{18}$$