# How to find the probability that 5 appears twice before both 4 and 6 appear when a fair six-sided die is rolled

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, dice

This is from QuantGuide(Doubly 5 II):
Jenny has a fair 6−sided die with numbers 1−6 on the sides. Jenny continually rolls the die and keeps track of the outcomes in the order they appear. Jenny rolls until she sees two 5s (not necessarily consecutive) OR both 4 and 6. Find the probability Jenny stops rolling due to seeing two 5s.
My Approach:
The following cases to be considered are: 
When Jenny stops after seeing 2 5s before 4 and 6. Its probability will be:
\begin{equation}
P = \Sigma_{n \ge 2}\frac{1}{6^2}\binom{n-1}{1}\binom{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3})^{n-2}=0.5
\end{equation}
When Jenny stops after seeing 4 and 6 and no 5 being rolled.
\begin{equation}
P = \Sigma_{n \ge 2}\frac{1}{6^2}\binom{n-1}{1}\binom{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3})^{n-2}=0.5
\end{equation}
When Jenny stops after seeing 4 and 6 and one 5 is rolled.
\begin{equation}
P = \Sigma_{n \ge 3}\frac{1}{6^3}\binom{n-1}{1}\binom{n-2}{1}\binom{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3})^{n-3}=0.25
\end{equation}
Hence the conditional probability will be $P=\frac{0.5}{0.5+0.5+0.25}=0.4$. But this answer doesn't work.
Please suggest where I'm going wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782246/quant-interview-question-die-rolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is a bit strange - it's not clear why you think your series represent values you describe, and how you get probability greater than $1$ in denominator.

Define success as "having two fives before having both $4$ and $6$", and denote

- $p_{00}$ - probability of success before we have any 4,5 or 6
- $p_{10}$ - probability of success after having one 5, but no 4 or 6
- $p_{01}$ - probability of success after having one from 4 or 6, but no 5s (it doesn't matter if we have 4 or 6)
- $p_{11}$ - probability of success after having one from 4 or 6, and one 5

From symmetry, $p_{11} = \frac{1}{2}$.

The rest, checking what we can roll
$$p_{00} = \frac{3}{6} \cdot p_{00} + \frac{2}{6} \cdot p_{01} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot p_{10}$$
$$p_{10} = \frac{3}{6} \cdot p_{10} + \frac{2}{6} \cdot p_{11} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 1$$
$$p_{01} = \frac{4}{6} \cdot p_{01} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot p_{11} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 0$$

From this, we can find $p_{01} = \frac{1}{4}$, $p_{10} = \frac{2}{3}$ and $p_{00} = \frac{7}{18}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate $p_{00}$?

Comment: When we just start, we can 1) with probability $3/6$ roll 1,2 or 3 - that means we essentially ignore that roll, and go back to start; 2) with probability $2/6$ roll $4$ or $6$, and go to situation $p_{01}$; 3) with probability $1/6$ roll $5$ and go to situation $p_{10}$.